# if the $|a|=|a-b|=|c|, |a+b|=\sqrt{3}|c|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Assmue that $a,b,c$ be nonzero complex numbers,and such
$$|a|=|a-b|=|c|,~~~~|a+b|=\sqrt{3}|c|$$

Find the value
$$\log_{|c|}|(a\overline {b})^{2017}+(\overline{a}b)^{2017}|$$

I have try : Note 
$$|a-b|^2+|a+b|^2=2(|a|^2+|b|^2)$$ then
$$|c|^2+3|c|^2=2|a|^2+2|b|^2$$
and $|a|=|c|$, so we have
$$|a|=|b|=|c|$$
then I can't following try

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you might as well let $a$ be real and positive because you can rotate all the points that way without changing anything.  Can you find the angle between $a$ and $b$?  Note the $|a+b|=\sqrt 3 |c|=\sqrt 3 |a|$  Then note that $(a\overline b+\overline a b)=Re(ab)$

Comment: why $a$ is postive real number?

Comment: I am suggesting that once you prove it for $a$ real and positive you can claim that your proof works for any $a$ by rotating $b$ and $c$ by the same amount.  It actually doesn't matter, but it makes it easier to visualize the angle between $a$ and $b$.